# CSS media queries min-width and min-device-width conflicting?

Tags: css, media-queries

I am very new to the world of media queries, and it's clear there's something fundamental I'm missing about the difference between width and device-width -- other than their obvious targeting capacities.

I would like to target both regular computers and devices with the same breakpoints, so I just duplicated all of my min & max width queries to min-device and max-device width queries.  For whatever reason, when I add the -device counterparts, my CSS is interpreted very differently by regular computers, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[You can see the effects here](http://www.swanflighthaven.com/pagestuff/correct.jpg) (this is what it SHOULD look like)

[And here](http://www.swanflighthaven.com/pagestuff/incorrect.jpg) (after adding -device-width to my queries, my CSS gets screwed up at the smallest width -- the larger resolutions are seen even when the browser width is smaller than what is getting called).

Here are my CSS links -- is there something wrong with my syntax? :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 674px), only screen and (max-device-width: 674px)" href="300.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 675px) and (max-width: 914px), only screen and (min-device-width: 675px) and (max-device-width: 914px)" href="650.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 915px) and (max-width: 1019px), only screen and (min-device-width: 915px) and (max-device-width: 1019px)" href="915.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 1020px), only screen and (min-device-width: 1020px)" href="1020.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1299px), only screen and (min-device-width: 1200px) and (max-device-width: 1299px)" href="1200.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 1300px), only screen and (min-device-width: 1300px)" href="1300.css">
```

Comment: In FF both versions looks exactly the same to me. In what browser and version you have the problems?

Comment: FF 12.  Make sure you drag slowly from the widest to the smallest so it can see the other queries.  I see this problem in every browser I tried -- FF, Chrome, etc -- I'm not sure if you're trying it at the smaller widths.

Comment: Here's screenshots off FF 12 and Chrome 25 http://www.swanflighthaven.com/pagestuff/correct.jpg and http://www.swanflighthaven.com/pagestuff/incorrect.jpg

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Device-width refers to the display's resolution (eg. the 1024 from 1024x768), while width refers to the width of the browser itself (which will be different from the resolution if the browser isn't maximized).  If your resolution is large enough to get you in one break point, but the width of the browser is small enough to get you in another one, you'll end up with an odd combination of both.

Unless you have a legitimate reason to restrict the style sheets based on the resolution and not the size of the viewport, then just use `min-width`/`max-width` and avoid `min-device-width`/`max-device-width`.

Comment: Ahhh.  Well that makes perfect sense.  Thank you so much for explaining that concisely!  I feel idiotic I didn't understand this from the reading I've done.  But question:  how do I target mobile devices AND computers?

Comment: Are all devices targeted (Iphones, Ipads etc) if I skip the device-width?

Comment: Because mobile devices typically have their browsers maximized, device-width and width will be the same.

Comment: But, typically if you want your website design to adapt to the browser's width I guess it's better to go for min/max-width instead of device-width isn't it? I mean if my users want to browse my website with a minimized browser it's their own choice isn't it ? It would feel like a failure to me if the design would go nuts when I'm playing with my browser's size. I guess it's up to what you want to do.

Comment: Excellent post and concise answer.

Comment: According to this article https://www.sitepoint.com/media-queries-width-vs-device-width/, the answer should be a bit more complex.

Comment: With device width only one images will be downloaded, with window width resizing the window could span a breakpoint then multiple images will be downloaded!

Comment: **Be careful**, `device-width` is now deprecated. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64757835/3048967) below.

Answer (score 8):

`device-width` is deprecated in Media Queries Level 4.
Refer to MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width) for more details.

> Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

So, `width` and `height` features should be used to consider the width and height of the viewport respectively.

P.S. These are range features they can be prefixed with `min-` or `max-` to express "minimum condition" or "maximum condition" constraints. Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but how would you approach styles for large mobile landscapes (above 760px)? Without using device-width, the mobile landscape styles are still being applied to desktops when I target large mobile phones for landscape styles.