# CSS Media Query don't working in css file

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Added this line in index.html:

```
 <link href="css/style.css" media="all  "rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And this is my Media Query CSS:

```
    /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
     #mapArea .white span {
        width: 100px;
     }

}
```

But when i check it in browser, don't working. What's my problem? How can i fix it?

(Tested all modern browsers)

Comment: check the browser version. Should be latest to test this.. CSS 3 feature

Comment: @Nirus thank you. Tested all modern browsers. My main browser is Chrome and its version 27.0.1453.116 m

Comment: Maybe the spaces in the link are causing issues?, try `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">`

Comment: ... f="css/style.css" media="all  "rel="styles ...   check your typo.

Comment: Related subject : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276218/css-media-queries-min-width-and-min-device-width-conflicting#15276588

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@media only screen` has different definition with `@media screen`.

> The keyword ‘only’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older
>   user agents. User agents must process media queries starting with
>   ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Maybe you can try change into this:

```
@media screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {
  .white span {
      width: 100px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You are querying for `device-width`, which if your on a laptop or desktop isn't going to fire those queries. Change those to `min-width` and you should see the query work.

Also, make sure you have a `viewport` meta tag i.e. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">` in the `<head>` of your HTML.

Comment: The meta tag was the solution in my case. Had the same issue - css was working properly on one page, but didn't work on a mirror page. REMEMBER THE META TAG

Comment: Yes! How come I've never seen mention of the meta tag needed in all the media queries tutorials I've read? Thank you so much!