# CSS media query not detecting orientation change

Tags: css, cordova, orientation, media-queries

I am using Cordova to make a hybrid app.

I have the following media queries in my css file

```
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (orientation: portrait) {
        /*css goes here*/
     }

    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (orientation: landscape) {
        /*css goes here*/
    }
```

and similarly media queries for all sorts of device width in both portrait and landscape orientation.

When I test my app on Nexus 4, it doesn't detect the orientation change and change the css, example, if I start the app in portrait mode, then based on the device width it picks up the media query of that width in the portrait mode, however if then I change the orientation of the phone, it doesn't detect the new width and apply the new css of the corresponding width and landscape orientation and vice versa.

Am I missing something here, isn't CSS Media query supposed to detect the change in orientation by itself and apply the appropriate CSS?

Comment: Try `min-width` instead of `min-device-width` to check if this also does not work.

Comment: min-width worked! On the actual devices that is, in chrome device emulation it's not working for some reason.

Comment: sometimes there are dependencies that an emulator can't show, so we need to test it into actual devices. I think you need to tweak your emulator for it to work there too. Try searching it will help xD

Comment: Even when the media query itself is correct, a Cordova / PhoneGap app on iOS may still require some JavaScript to actually process the orientation change to landscape and therefore get to the CSS. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999435/why-doesnt-my-cordova-phonegap-ios-app-rotate-when-the-device-rotates/ ... which took me quite awhile to find.

Comment: @rockstar - You should have added your comment as an answer as this was helpful for me as well. "min-width" instead of "min-device-width" served my media queries properly on orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue with this, where I would have a specific media query for portrait landscape and another for landscape, and it would switch fine from portrait to landscape the first time, but when you went back it wasn't updating.

@rockStar should get the credit for the answer, but using min-width instead of min-device-width did the trick for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i have been busy with my studies lately so i couldn't check stuff around here this days, Upon request,

using `min-width` is better than using `min-device-width`

and the reason would be in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276218/css-media-queries-min-width-and-min-device-width-conflicting)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CSS selector based on portrait and landscape mode, i.e you can use a class in landscape mode and apply css and remove the class when in portrait mode and apply css. So basically you can check whether a class exists or not.