# Remove Mobile-Menu Button from desktop site

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu, desktop

I'm working on a HTML site and adding a mobile menu. I was able to add the menu but having trouble with the button that opens that menu.  This is what I have.

```
<a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr">
<img class="hidedesktop" src="img/menu-icon.png" alt="Menu">
</a>
```

And when I press the image it opens the menu.  I need it to remove this from the page on desktop and show on mobile. I've been doing some research and found that

```
display:none;
```

should work in the @media but I tried and wasn't able to set this up correctly. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Below is my CSS for hide desktop.

```
.hidedesktop{
    display:block;
}
```

and CSS for @media remove on desktop

```
/*@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.hidedesktop{
    display:block;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.hidedesktop{
    display:none;
}
    }
}
*/
```

I would like to also hide the main menu on the mobile version but if I get help with this I think I'll figure that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need min-width for it.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .hidedesktop {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Or to use min-device-width if you want (**unlikely**), make sure to check out the link below if you're not sure about it.

```
@media only screen and (min-devide-width: 768px) {
    .hidedesktop {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

[Read here to learn the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15276588/483779)