# Why is my media query not working after first breakpoint?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make a simple webpage responsive but somehow, after the first breaking point, nothing happens. I put the whole code in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Cilvako/umwhLdqx/

Bellow are the breakpoints I am trying to use but still haven't got to the third since I couldn't make the second work.

/*Media Query*/

```
 @media screen and (min-device-width : 1px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {

       }

 @media screen and (min-width : 481px) and (max-width :  768px) {


      }




 @media screen and (min-width : 769px) and (max-width :  1200px) {


    }




    @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix `device-width` with the normal `width` if you can. Simply use `min-width` and `max-width` if you're targeting only browser window size.

Read this if you're confused [CSS media queries min-width and min-device-width conflicting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276218/css-media-queries-min-width-and-min-device-width-conflicting)

Comment: Thx, will do, I really can't figure things out with this media queries yet. My problem was that I forgot some brackets. I feel so stupid.

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to write CSS in the media queries and also close and open them properly using '{' and '}' which you are not on the fiddle.

Comment: True, I forgot some curly brackets indeed. All good now, thx.

Answer (score 1):

A media query looks something like

```
@media screen and (min-width : 769px) and (max-width : 1199px) {
    h1 { color: blue; }
}

@media screen and (min-width : 1200px) and (max-width : 1800px) {
    h1 { color: green; }
}
```

So between 769px and 1199px, `h1`s would be blue, and between 1200px and 1800px they would be green. I'm not seeing that in your JSFiddle - the brackets are not closed properly, and I can't see what you're trying to do with the rules.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I forgot to close a curly bracket. Still very new at this and still loosing brackets on the way. Thx, now eveything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You almost never ever ever need a `max-width`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/x7msfgny/)

```
body {
  background: gray;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  body {
    background: lightblue;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    background: orange;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  body {
    background: pink;
  }
}
```

Comment: So it's a matter of how you chose t write the code after all? I am asking because I see most media queris written with min and max width.

Comment: @SilviaBogdan in my experience, `max-width` media queries are extremely useful. Perhaps what @Sheriffderek is getting at is that, if you're doing mobile-first, then `min-width`s are definitely more important. You only want to style something that way when the screen is at least that size, whereas frequently using `max-size` can be a code smell (either hacky code or not DRY code), but CSS is hard and when you're in the real world, `max-size` is very useful.

Comment: Correct. They can be useful, but chances are - you aren't going to find great ways to use them until you've mastered the min-width... for example, I use a min and max for a specific type of grid so that I don't have to write over :nth-of-type rules   - http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/azRpRM  --- However, C is for cascade - and you'll almost always write less styles with little tweaks than with targeted style areas.