# Media query not taking effect on browser resize

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm working on a site that will make it responsive. Media queries are working on the device it self but on browser resize it's not taking effect. This is my code. Did I missed something? Thanks in advance!

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width :     
480px) and (orientation: portrait) {

  //Code Here

}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width :  
480px) and (orientation: landscape) {

  //Code Here

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are targeting `device-width`.

You need to change your `@media queries` to:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width :     
480px) and (orientation: portrait) {

  //Code Here

}
```

Also, the `orientation` won't work in this instance (in your browser).

Comment: great! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

When you use 'device' you're telling it to base it off the resolution of the actual screen, rather than the browser width (which is what min-width achieves).

Refer to the following question in regards to the difference between using min-width with/without device.

[CSS media queries min-width and min-device-width conflicting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276218/css-media-queries-min-width-and-min-device-width-conflicting)