# window.innerWidth If Not Firing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get a dropdown menu to show when the size of the screen is smaller than 500px. Later, I will remove the navbar so that this menu replaces it on small devices.

Code looks good to me and the alert DOES fire but the menu doesn't show.

**TLDR: Need to make the menu show when screen size is less than 500px**

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mcgettrm/y4edsu73/

Code:

```js
var dropDownFunction = function(){
 var menuContent = document.getElementById("dropDownMenuClass");
 menuContent.classList.toggle("menuShow");
}


var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

 if(windowWidth < 500){
  alert("window is too small");
  
  var dropDownMenu = getElementById("dropDownMenu");
  dropDownMenu.classList.toggle("mainMenuShow");
  
  
  
 }
```

```css
#dropDownMenu {
 
}
.dropDownMenuClass{
 display:none;
}
.mainMenuShow{
 display: block;
}

#dropDownMenuContent {
 
}
.dropDownMenuContentClass {
 display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 width:100%;
 text-align: center;
}
#dropDownMenuContent a {
 color: black;
 padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
 
}
#dropDownMenuContent a:hover {
 background-color: #f1f1f1;

}
#dropDownButton {
 width:100%;
 background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menuShow {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropDownMenu" class="dropDownMenuClass">
     <button onclick="dropDownFunction()" id="dropDownButton">MENU</button>
     <div id="dropDownMenuContent" class="dropDownMenuContentClass">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
      <a href="itprojects.html">IT Projects</a>
      <a href="languageprojects.html">Language Projects</a>
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      <a href="essays.html">Essays</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: An alternative way of doing this is with [media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050581/media-query-not-taking-effect-on-browser-resize).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementByID` is a method of `document`

```
var dropDownMenu = document.getElementById("dropDownMenu");
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I made the change and even though it works in the fiddle, I'm now getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null. Am I doing something wrong with classList?

Comment: You need to ensure that your script runs after the document is loaded. Otherwise `dropDownMenu` doesn't yet exist. Placing your script at the end of your document should fix the error

Comment: I was running it in a stylesheet but what I did was set up an event listener to fire the script once the page had loaded and that solved the problem. You were 100% correct. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Always check the console for errors. For example in Chrome you will see

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined
```

It should be:

```
var dropDownMenu = document.getElementById("dropDownMenu");
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y4edsu73/1/

Comment: Hey thanks! I made the change and even though it works in the fiddle, I'm now getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null.

Am I doing something wrong with classList?