# Media queries: background-image not displayed

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying [here](http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/) to add a different background image for every single page as soon you visit the website on mobile (Tablet and Smartphones).

As you can see, I am using **Wordpress** and **fullPage.js**

I tried this in CSS, but without any result:

```
/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
      #beste-lage { background-image: url(http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/text.png) !important; }
}

/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
      #beste-lage { background-image: url(http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/text.png) !important; }
}

/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 
      #beste-lage { background-image: url(http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/text.png) !important; }
}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 
      #beste-lage { background-image: url(http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/text.png) !important; }
}
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that media queries are working? try to add another property to verify it's inside one of this options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background isn't on `#beste-lage` but on `.bt-op-item-content`.

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout that you have not closed **quotes** - `"`

```
 #beste-lage { background-image: url("http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/text.png); }
```

should be:

```
#beste-lage { background-image: url(http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/text.png) }
```

Comment: Even if i change it does not works. Am I apply this to the wrong id?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `min-device-width` to `min-width`, that should do the trick. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276218/css-media-queries-min-width-and-min-device-width-conflicting) for more info!

Comment: Hmmm, strange.. Normally I just use `@media screen and (min-width: 414px) and (max-width: 736px) {}` without the pixel ration and screen only.