# Paragraph not displaying in small screens

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page width a full bleed image on the back ground a some text.
In small screens, I see a horizontal bar showing and part of the text is being hidden.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-image: url(FreeVector-Fresh-Beer.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
img {
  margin: auto;
}
.paragraph {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Alice', serif!important;
  color: #996633;
}
p a {
  color: #996633 !important;
  font-size: 35px !important;
  padding-top: 1%;
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 120px) and (max-device-width: 400px) {
  .paragraph {
    word-break: break-all;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="jumbotron">
  <figure>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="Craft-Beer-SA-min.png" alt="Chania">
  </figure>

  <div class="paragraph" style="font-size:50px">
    <p>Our Website Is Brewing ! ! !</p>
    <p>Coming To A Browser Near You. . .
      <br><a href="">info@me.co.uk</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

How can I keep the text visible and remove the scrolling bar?
And how can I also make the background image responsive so that I can see it all in any screen size?

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: It's because a single word is occupying more than 120px. In this case a min-width of 260px is required to ignore horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an nice explanation: [CSS media queries min-width and min-device-width conflicting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276218/css-media-queries-min-width-and-min-device-width-conflicting)

> `device-width` refers to the display's resolution (eg. the 1024 from
>   1024x768), while `width` refers to the width of the browser itself
>   (which will be different from the resolution if the browser isn't
>   maximized).

Additional reference: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml

**Solution:**

Instead of `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` use `min-width` and `max-width`.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-image: url(FreeVector-Fresh-Beer.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
img {
  margin: auto;
}
.paragraph {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Alice', serif!important;
  color: #996633;
}
p a {
  color: #996633 !important;
  font-size: 35px !important;
  padding-top: 1%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 120px) and (max-width: 400px) {
  .paragraph {
    word-break: break-all;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="jumbotron">
  <figure>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="Craft-Beer-SA-min.png" alt="Chania">
  </figure>

  <div class="paragraph" style="font-size:50px">
    <p>Our Website Is Brewing ! ! !</p>
    <p>Coming To A Browser Near You. . .
      <br><a href="">info@me.co.uk</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually just set the font-size to 5vw and it sorts everything out.
The next problem is in the background image. I see that it hides the content of it. How can I make it responsive so that I see the  entire image in any  screen size?